# How to validate an input with a 4-digit number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, input

I want to write a program that only accepts a 4-digit input from the user.
The problem is that I want the program to accept a number like `0007` but not a number like `7` (because it´s not a 4 digit number).

How can I solve this? This is the code that I´ve wrote so far:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("type in a number with four digits: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("sorry, i did not understand that! ")

    if number > 9999:
        print("The number is to big")
    elif number < 0:
        print("No negative numbers please!")
    else:
        break

print("Good! The number you wrote was", number)
```

But if I input 7 to it it will just say `Good! The number you wrote was 7`

Comment: Note that, before you make it an integer, the user's input is a string...

Answer (score 2):

Before casting the user's input into an integer, you can check to see if their input has 4 digits in it by using the `len` function:

```
len("1234")  # returns 4
```

However, when using the `int` function, Python turns `"0007"` into simple `7`. To fix this, you could store their number in a list where each list element is a digit.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of formatting for `print` purposes, modify your `print` statement:

```
print("Good! The number you wrote was {:04d}", number)
```

If you actually want to store the leading zeros, treat the number like a string.  This is probably not the most elegant solution but it should point you in the right direction:

```
while True:
try: 
    number = int(input("Type in a number with four digits: "))
except ValueError:
    print("sorry, i did not understand that! ")
if number > 9999:
    print("The number is to big")
elif number < 0:
    print("No negative numbers please!")
else:
    break

# determine number of leading zeros
length = len(str(number))
zeros = 0
if length == 1:
    zeros = 3
elif length == 2:
    zeros = 2
elif length == 3:
    zeros = 1

# add leading zeros to final number
final_number = ""
for i in range(zeros):
    final_number += '0'

# add user-provided number to end of string
final_number += str(number)

print("Good! The number you wrote was", final_number)
```

Comment: Apart from the indentation error in the while loop, why are you "constructing" the final number? The question specifically says *"I want the program to accept a number like 0007 __but not a number like 7__"*. If I input the number 7 your program will output `Good! The number you wrote was 0007`...

Answer (score -2):

```
pin = input("Please enter a 4 digit code!")
if pin.isdigit() and len(pin) == 4:
    print("You successfully logged in!")
else:
    print("Access denied! Please enter a 4 digit number!")
```